# Postgres health check in Elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir

I am trying to do a simple health check on my postgres database for elixir.

In rails I would do something like: `ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections`

Is there anything similar on elixir?

Comment: I think perhaps you're misunderstanding the Elixir idiom.  If you couldn't reach the DB for some reason you want the code to crash--big and immediate so you know you need to check the DB.  If you don't want the code to crash then build a supervisor and have it handle a DB failure. Either way, it's sort of not the Elixir way (or really the Erlang way either) to run a "simple health check" on a database.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best that I found.

```
status = try do
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(ProjectName.Repo, "select 1", [])
  :ok
rescue
  DBConnection.ConnectionError -> :error
end
```

It just sends a `select 1` request to the sql server and if we get an exit we return `:error` else we return `:ok`